# One or anyone in superlatives?

Tags: superlative-degree

In sentences with a superlative, which indefinite pronoun is more accurate: one or anyone?
I'm referring to sentences such as:

"It was the biggest cake one had ever seen."
"It was the biggest cake anyone had ever seen."

I'm assuming they are both correct, so, what is the difference between them in terms of meaning?

Thank you!

Comment: Arguably, the biggest cake anyone has ever seen trumps the biggest cake one has ever seen. Most of the time, anyway.

Comment: Your first version is an example of ***one*** being used as an alternative to ***I*** (the speaker), which is almost always archaic and/or facetious today.